# Unable to WDS two devices AP and Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wds

In an attempt to enable WDS (Wireless Distributed Service) on my Main Router I have failed to connect to my AP.

Enabled WDS inadvertently disabled the DHCP server on Main Router (even though the option is set) and any device connected to the main router cannot access the internet.

I cannot see either devices when connected to the respective device.

**Main Router**

- Netcomm NF2 N900
- SSID: SixStrings
- 192.168.20.1
- WDS Enabled - MAC Of AP Added
- DHCP Enabled
- Channel 7
- No Security

**AP**

- D Link 8200a AP
- SixStrings
- 192.168.20.5
- WDS Enabled - MAC Of Main Router Added
- DHCP Disabled
- Channel 7
- No Security Encryption

Comment: Did you make sure to add the WiFi MAC, not the Ethernet MAC?

Comment: Yes I have added the WiFi MAC to the devices